# Guice. Inject into constructor

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I have a singleton:

```
public class MySingleton{
  public static getInstance(){//typical singleton getInstance
    ...
  }

  //fields
  private static volatile instance;
  @Inject
  private AnotherClassInstanceThatIWantToInjectHere anotherClassInst_BlaBla;
  private MySingleton(){
    ...
    anotherClassInst_BlaBla.doSmth();//NullPointerException happens!
    ...
  }
}
```

What is cause of this NPE? Does it happens because it is constructor or because it is singleton?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the constructor of `MySingleton` is invoked, `instance` is null. `Guice` has to construct the instance of MySingleton before it has anything to inject into.

Guice has a concept of singletons: either you bind the class in singleton scope in your module, or you annotate the class as `@Singleton`. Then you just inject like usual:

```
@Singleton
public class MySingleton {
  private AnotherClassInstanceThatIWantToInjectHere anotherClassInst_BlaBla;

  @Inject public MySingleton(AnotherClassInstanceThatIWantToInjectHere anotherClassInst_BlaBla) {
    this.anotherClassInst_BlaBla = anotherClassInst_BlaBla;
    anotherClassInst_BlaBla.doSmth();
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, but what it mean? That I can't access injected fields in constructor?

Answer (score 1):

anotherClassInst_BlaBla is an instance variable in this case, I guess that's why you choose setter injection. Since it's an instance variable and also setter injection needs an instance to set this variable to, an instance of MySingleton class needs to be created/constructed to use anotherClassInst_BlaBla.

Shortly, you should call doSmth() method after the constructor MySingleton() is invoked because setter injection happens after an instance is constructed.

Comment: No, that's not working. I don't know why, but when I moved job from constructor to another (init()) method, I still had NPE.

Comment: If you you use [initialization block](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html), it still leads to NPE because initialization block occurs before the constructor. You could use constructor injection as @IvanZelenskyy suggested, or inject it by the container and add [PostConstructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html) method to call doSmith() method. But a problem is that ideally, either of those ways, your singleton will be no longer singleton since it has public constructor. Anyone could create an instance of MySingleton class.

Comment: I use the way from @AndyTurner's answer, and it works. singleton annotation and inject into constructor.